# instantiates class using ninject ioc in .net

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ninject

I am using Ninject to do some IoC in my ASP.NET MVC application.

I have an interface "IService.cs" :

```
public interface IService
{
    string method();
}
```

I have the corresponding implementation "Service.cs" :

```
public class Service
{
    string method()
    {
        return "result";
    }
}
```

I have done the binding in another class heriting from NinjectModule :

```
public class MyNinjectModule : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        RegisterServices();
    }

    private void RegisterServices()
    {
        Kernel.Bind<IService>().To<Service>();
    }

}
```

I have my class A which use this service :

```
public class A
{
    private readonly IService _service;
    private int i;

    public A(IService service, int i)
    {
        this._service=service;
        this.i=i;
    }        

}
```

The problem is that now, I don't know how to instantiate my class A in my application. This is where am I stuck, how can I call Ninject
to tell my app to go get the implementation of my interface:

```
var myClass=new A(????)
```

Comment: I assume that's its really `.To<Service>()` (not `To<IService>()`)

Comment: Yes sorry, I correct it

Comment: Its just `var myClass=new A()` - `_service` will be the concrete class

Comment: I simplify my class A for the post, but the actual constructor is the following : public A(IService service,int i)

Comment: `var myClass=new A(5)` should work (although have not tested it)

Comment: No, I am having the following error : constructor has 2 parameters but is invoked with 1 argument

Comment: Surely `public class Service` should be `public class Service : IService`

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is that your `Service` class does not implement `IService`.

```
public class Service
{
    string method()
    {
        return "result";
    }
}
```

It should be

```
public class Service : IService
{
    public string method()
    {
        return "result";
    }
}
```

But as for instantiating a class, the best approach is to use a [composition root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/) to build an object graph. In MVC, that is best handled by implementing `IControllerFactory`.

```
public class NinjectControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
{
    private readonly IKernel kernel;

    public NinjectControllerFactory(IKernel kernel)
    {
        this.kernel = kernel;
    }

    protected override IController GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
    {
        return controllerType == null
                   ? null
                   : (IController)this.kernel.Get(controllerType);
    }
}
```

## Usage

```
using System;
using Ninject;
using DI;
using DI.Ninject;
using DI.Ninject.Modules;

internal class CompositionRoot
{
    public static void Compose()
    {
        // Create the DI container
        var container = new StandardKernel();

        // Setup configuration of DI
        container.Load(new MyNinjectModule());

        // Register our ControllerFactory with MVC
        ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new NinjectControllerFactory(container));
    }
}
```

In `Application_Start`, add:

```
CompositionRoot.Compose();
```

You will also need to create an interface for your class `A` and register it. An integer cannot be resolved automatically, you have to do that explicitly.

```
Kernel.Bind<IClassA>().To<A>()
    .WithConstructorArgument("i", 12345);
```

And then you would add your dependency to a controller. Dependencies of dependencies are resolved automatically.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly IClassA classA;

    public HomeController(IClassA classA)
    {
        if (classA == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("classA");

        this.classA = classA;
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        // Use this.classA here...
        // IService will be automatically injected to it.

        ViewBag.Message = "Modify this template to jump-start your ASP.NET MVC application.";

        return View();
    }
}
```